# Eclipse custom Rename Participant to rename a file, its references and folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like override the Navigator popup menu -> Rename functionality by using a custom RenameParticipant. The requirement is to 
1 . To rename the file selected, 
2. Search and replace its references in all files (without extension) 
3. Rename a folder with same name (without extension).

E.g. Let say the file selected for rename is "mystuff.flow:, then there exists a folder by name "mystuff". The rename participant should rename this folder as well.

I'm able to achieve first two requirements with the following code but stuck with the third one.

### plugin.xml

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants">
  <renameParticipant
        class="com....flow.refactoring.MyflowRenameParticipant"
        id="com.....flow.refactoring.myflowRenameParticipant"
        name="MyflowRenameParticipant">
     <enablement>
         <and>
        <instanceof
              value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
        </instanceof>
        <test
              property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
              value="flow">
        </test>
     </and>
     </enablement>
  </renameParticipant>
```

### Custom Rename Participant

```
public class MyflowRenameParticipant extends RenameParticipant {

    @Override
    public Change createChange(IProgressMonitor pm) throws CoreException,
        OperationCanceledException {
    final HashMap<IFile, TextFileChange> changes= new HashMap<IFile, TextFileChange>();


    // Use the text search engine to find matches in files
    // limit to the current project
    IResource[] roots= { fFile.getProject() };  
    String[] fileNamePatterns= { "*" }; //$NON-NLS-1$ 
    FileTextSearchScope scope= FileTextSearchScope.newSearchScope(roots , fileNamePatterns, false);
    FileNamePatternSearchScope fscope= FileNamePatternSearchScope.newSearchScope("Folders Imp", roots , false);

    // only find the simple name of the file without extention
    Pattern pattern= Pattern.compile(getNameWithoutExt(fFile)); 
    TextSearchRequestor collector= new TextSearchRequestor() {
        public boolean acceptPatternMatch(TextSearchMatchAccess matchAccess) throws CoreException {
            IFile file= matchAccess.getFile();
            TextFileChange change= (TextFileChange) changes.get(file);
            if (change == null) {
                // an other participant already modified that file?
                TextChange textChange= getTextChange(file); 
                if (textChange != null) {
                    // don't try to merge changes
                    return false; 
                }
                change= new TextFileChange(file.getName(), file);
                change.setEdit(new MultiTextEdit());
                changes.put(file, change);
            }
            ReplaceEdit edit= new ReplaceEdit(matchAccess.getMatchOffset(), matchAccess.getMatchLength(), newName);
            change.addEdit(edit);
            change.addTextEditGroup(new TextEditGroup("Updates text reference", edit)); //$NON-NLS-1$
            return true;
        }
    };
    TextSearchEngine.create().search(scope, collector, pattern, pm);

    if (changes.isEmpty())
        return null;

    CompositeChange result= new CompositeChange("Callflow  Updates"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    for (Iterator<TextFileChange> iter= changes.values().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        result.add((Change) iter.next());
    }
          // Gets the folder to be renamed.
    IFolder folder = getMyflowFolder(fFile);

           // How to add this to the result? so that the same is available in the context for preview and subsequent rename operation.

    return result;
}
```

Appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add an instance of `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.resource.RenameResourceChange` (or maybe `MoveResourceChange`) for the `IFolder` to your `CompositeChange` result.

Comment: RenameResourceChange rrChange = new RenameResourceChange(folder.getProjectRelativePath() ,"subflow/"+newName);
  result.add(rrChange);

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I'm getting fatal error "No input element provide". Is anything wrong with this code? RenameResourceChange rrChange = new RenameResourceChange(folder.getProjectRelativePath() ,"subflow/"+newName);
  result.add(rrChange); I tried folder.getLocation() etc.

Comment: Thanks Greg. This solved the problem - RenameResourceChange rrChange = new RenameResourceChange(folder.getFullPath() ,newName);